# SQL query in python script with HTML code

Tags: php, html, mysql, ubuntu

I was playing around with MySQL, Python and HTML. What I'm trying to do is write a python script that echoes HTML code and put certain values from a database in the HTML code. This is wat I have:

```
echo "<div class='IssueInformation'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<div class='IssueCoverDiv'><img class='IssueCover' src='`echo $row['Image'];`'</div>";
  }
echo "</div>";
echo "</BODY></HTML>";
```

However I get following error when I check the script with php5 /var/www/script.php

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /var/www/script2.php on line 51
```

There is something wrong with the line of code between the while brackets but it beats me.

Any ideas? Thanx!

Comment: that's not Python.. it's PHP

Comment: Use string concatenation correctly: `echo "<div class='IssueCoverDiv'><img class='IssueCover' src='".echo $row['Image'];."'</div>";
`

Comment: @karthikr Um... that would be invalid too. `echo "<div class='IssueCoverDiv'><img class='IssueCover' src='{$row['Image']}'</div>";` would do the trick.

Comment: Ofcourse it's PHP, don't know why I said Python.. Works like a charm btw!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your string concatenation. Fixed it:

```
echo "<div class='IssueCoverDiv'><img class='IssueCover' src='".$row['Image']."'</div>";
```

You should read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Interesting guide, thanx!